# How to find dim(U)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

1. Let $V$ be an $n$ -dimensional vector space and let $W \subseteq V$ be an $m$ -dimensional subspace. For each $\mathbf{v} \in V$, define $S_{\mathbf{v}}=\{\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w}: \mathbf{w} \in W\}$, and let $U=\left\{S_{\mathbf{v}}: \mathbf{v} \in V\right\}$. Define addition in $U$ so that for any $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in V$
   $$
   S_{\mathbf{x}}+S_{\mathbf{y}}=S_{\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}}
   $$
   and define scalar multiplication so that for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$
   $$
   k S_{\mathbf{x}}=S_{k \mathbf{x}}
   $$
   It can be shown that $U$ is vector space (you do not need to prove this).

Given the above information, I need to find what dim($U$) is.

This is what I have done:

Given $W \subseteq V$ with $\operatorname{dim}(W)=m \leq n=\operatorname{dim}(V)$. For each $v \in V$, define $S_{v}=\{v+w: w \in W\}$ and let $U=\left\{S_{v}: v \in V\right\}$

Let the basis for $V$ be the set $\left\{v_{1}, v_{2}, \ldots, v_{n}\right\}$ and the basis for $W$ be the set $\left\{w_{1}, w_{2}, \ldots, w_{m}\right\}$.

By the definition of $S_{v}$, for each $v_{i'}s$ we have

$S_{v_{1}}=\left\{v_{1}+w_{1}, v_{1}+w_{2}, \ldots, v_{1}+w_{m}\right\}$

$S_{v_{2}}=\left\{v_{2}+w_{1}, v_{2}+w_{2}, \ldots, v_{2}+w_{m}\right\}$

$\vdots$

$S_{v_{n}}=\left\{v_{n}+w_{1}, v_{n}+w_{2}, \ldots, v_{n}+w_{m}\right\}$

The above sets are constructed based on the basis vectors of $V$ and $W$. Thus every $S_{v_{i}}{ }^{\prime} s$ are unique.

And $U$ is defined to be the set of all $S_{v_{i'}}s$, we have the set

$U=\left\{S_{v_{1}}, S_{v_{2}}, \ldots, S_{v_{n}}\right\}$, where $v_{i} \in V, 1 \leq i \leq n$

As there are $n$ vectors in the set, we have $\operatorname{dim}(U)=n$.

Would this be correct?

Comment: No.  $W$ contains more than just a set of basis vectors, so $S_v$ contains more than just $m$ elements.

Comment: Note that by the way things have been defined, the map $v \to S_v$ defines a linear map from $V$ onto $U$. The rank-nullity theorem may provide a helpful change of perspective.

Comment: @user10354138. That's fair enough. Thank you.

Comment: @leslietownes. Thank you for the advice. It is definitely helpful.